# Azure event hub End of stream reached while consuming message C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm using Azure eventhub with schema registry. I'm sending a message with a huge string.
The message has property JsonConent. I am using Avro schema for nullable string with a default value.
I am trying to convert the message to GenericRecord, when I consume it, but when the JsonContent is too large I have an error: Avro.AvroException - End of stream reached.

```
public async Task ProcessEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs arg)
{
    var a = avroSerializer.Deserialize(arg.Data.EventBody.ToStream(), typeof(GenericRecord);
}
```

```
I am using Azure.Data.SchemaRegistry.ApacheAvro 1.0.0-beta.1,
Azure.Messaging.EventHubs 5.3.0-beta.4,
Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor 5.3.0-beta.4
```

Comment: is it larger than 1MB?

Comment: The Event Hubs clients and service treat the body of an event as an opaque stream of bytes; neither will inspect, modify, or otherwise make inferences.   The most likely cause for this type of error is that the body isn't well-formed when publishing.    It would be helpful to see how your events are formed and sent.

Comment: No, it wasn't larger than 1MB. I'm facing the problem when I was sending a large string, only when I use a schema registry. Maybe It is from the beta version of the Eventhub. I reduced the string size and everything is working for now. I found an issue, logged in the apache Jira board, related to this error, so maybe Microsoft is referencing this version in their nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2983), logged into the apache Jira board. Maybe Microsoft Azure is using it.